# Mouseout event not firing in Rafael.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, raphael

I have a number of shapes drawn using Raphael.js that I need to add a shadow to and enlarge slightly when the mouse rolls over. I have everything working perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer, the `mouseout` event doesn't appear to fire.

This is the `mouseover`/`mouseout` code I have for each hexagon shape (hexagon is a reference to the rafael element, `this`/`_Promise` being a reference to a class that defines the events among other things):

```
    this.hexagon.mouseover(function(){
        _Promise.hexagon.toFront();
        _Promise.hexagon.attr( { "transform": "...s" + scaleAmountOnRollover } );
        _Promise.shadow = _Promise.hexagon.glow({ "width": 8, "opacity": 0.4 });
    });

    this.hexagon.mouseout(function(){
        _Promise.hexagon.attr( { "transform": "...s" + (1/scaleAmountOnRollover) } );
        _Promise.shadow.remove();
    });
```

In IE (up to and including version 9), the hexagon shapes just keep getting bigger and bigger because the `mouseout` event isn't firing. I've put some `console.logs` in there to check this is definitely the case.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you can add some code to http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can mess about with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the event bubbling mechanism differs on IE, thus generates unstable behavior for `mouseover` / `mouseout` events, but their innovation (yes, we're still talking IE!) comes to the rescue.

you can use IE's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of the standard `mouseover` and `mouseout` in order to achieve a consistent behavior. you will, of course, have to step down from Raphaël's API and implement these separately: bind another event listener and pass the IE specific event types, as you will have to call legacy code for versions 6-8, use `attachEvent` on these, or `addEventListener` for version 9 onward.

you can read more about these IE-specific events on [the quirksmode article on the subject](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html).

if you prefer to use jQuery for this, they have already thought of that by providing [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) as part of the API.