# CSS not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

This CSS works in IE8 and newer (and in Chrome), but not in IE7. Specifically, the tooltip just doesn't appear when I hover over the div. What do I need to change for IE7 (and IE6)?

```css
.headertooltip, .headertooltip:visited
{
    color: #0077AA;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 20px;
}

.headertooltip div
{
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 82px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 900px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.headertooltip:hover div
{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the code to use mouse events to show the div/tooltip, but that still isn't working in IE7. That makes me think the problem lies in my markup/CSS.

I tried to create a sample in jsFiddle. It doesn't work, but you get the idea. Hovering the mouse over the little black box on the left (which I added just so you can see the target) should make the tooltip appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/szyN4/

Comment: Please show us a jsfiddle example.

Comment: The tooltip doesn't appear when I hover over the div to which this CSS is applied.

Comment: I wish down-voting required an explanation. It would make the lives of pricks a bit more difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, Vinny. Thanks for the idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 has minimal support for the `:hover` pseudo class, and IE7's is incomplete.

Try and change the `.headertooltip:hover div` to `.headertooltip div:hover` to please the oddities of IE's bubbling mechanism. It may solve your issue (you'll have to include it in a conditional stylesheet for IE7 only, of course).

You may also use JavaScript to sidestep this by implementing `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. See [a posted answer of mine on IE's innovation regarding mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518865/547020) for a quick reference.

#### References

- [CSS support table on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)
- [`mouseover` and `mouseout` on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html)

Comment: Developing for multiple browsers (especially old ones) is such a pain in the neck! Thanks for the info. I think it will be helpful.

Comment: @birdus - The simple solution is not to support insecure browsers like IE7 and IE6.  Considering Microsoft does not even support them you should encourage your vistors not to use them.

Comment: @Ramhound, this is not always possible, or even desired. users will act on their will, and should be allowed to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE6 is the current official browser of the company I'm currently on contract for. It's quite a large company and there's really no way I could influence a change in this respect. I've complained, but to no avail.

Comment: Changing .headertooltip:hover div to .headertooltip div:hover didn't fix the problem, but broke all the other browsers. I'll look into the mouseenter/mouseleave solution.

Comment: whoops, i meant use it in a conditional stylesheet. sorry to hear it didn't do the trick. i'll update my answer regardless to disclaim.